# Copy Entire row and paste In sheet if the value equals 2

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Workbook where  sheet1 has is formatted as a table the first column has a listed of numbers and then some items next to it. exmaple:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3    Column4
   1        Blue       Green     Yellow
   2        Apple      Grape      Mango
   3       Computer    Phone      Tablet
```

I want to create VBA Module where if I enter the number "2" in the range Sheet2.A1 it will can copy the row:

```
2        Apple      Grape      Mango
```

And Paste it in sheet2.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to copy the 4 cells over. The code below gets copied into the module for `Sheet1`. `Target` is checked to make sure it's the first column and only a single cell is being edited.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then
        Target.Resize(ColumnSize:=4).Copy Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1)
    End If
End Sub
```

There's a lot more that couldbe done but the above should help give a framework. Have a look at [Worksheet.Change Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) and [Range Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel) as well since they are what's used to accomplish this.